# Can not connect Kinect using openni

Tags: kinect, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**My system is ubuntu 14.04. I used to use openni to connect to my kinect1(one weeks ago). But It keeps fail these days when I type the command "roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch" I searched a lot but I can not find any answer. Here is the error info, hopes someone can help me!!!!**

```
crl@crl-MS-7666:~$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch 
... logging to /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/roslaunch-crl-MS-7666-23796.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://crl-MS-7666:49849/



PARAMETERS
 * /camera/camera_nodelet_manager/num_worker_threads: 4
 * /camera/depth_rectify_depth/interpolation: 0
 * /camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth/interpolation: 0
 * /camera/disparity_depth/max_range: 4.0
 * /camera/disparity_depth/min_range: 0.5
 * /camera/disparity_registered_hw/max_range: 4.0
 * /camera/disparity_registered_hw/min_range: 0.5
 * /camera/disparity_registered_sw/max_range: 4.0
 * /camera/disparity_registered_sw/min_range: 0.5
 * /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url: 
 * /camera/driver/depth_frame_id: /camera_depth_opt...
 * /camera/driver/depth_registration: False
 * /camera/driver/device_id: #1
 * /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url: 
 * /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id: /camera_rgb_optic...
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.10

NODES
  /camera/
    camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_points (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_registered_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_registered_hw (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_registered_sw (nodelet/nodelet)
    driver (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_hw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_sw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_ir (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_mono (nodelet/nodelet)
    register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
  /
    camera_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [23814]
[ INFO] [1437514907.975392896]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
process[camera/driver-2]: started with pid [23835]
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
process[camera/debayer-3]: started with pid [23854]
[ INFO] [1437514908.274749522]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1437514908.274835388]: 1. device on bus 002:11 is a SensorKinect (2ae) from PrimeSense (45e) with serial id 'A00362A09828132A'
[ INFO] [1437514908.275605423]: Searching for device with index = 1
process[camera/rectify_mono-4]: started with pid [23874]
[ INFO] [1437514908.447609480]: Opened 'SensorKinect' on bus 2:11 with serial number 'A00362A09828132A'
process[camera/rectify_color-5]: started with pid [23933]
process[camera/rectify_ir-6]: started with pid [23955]
process[camera/depth_rectify_depth-7]: started with pid [23971]
[FATAL] [1437514908.907439805]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1437514908.907507249]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1437514908.910206753]: Service call failed!
[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1] process has died [pid 23814, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-1.log].
log file: /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-1*.log
process[camera/depth_metric_rect-8]: started with pid [23993]
[camera/rectify_mono-4] process has died [pid 23874, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=rgb/image_mono image_rect:=rgb/image_rect_mono __name:=rectify_mono __log:=/home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-rectify_mono-4.log].
log file: /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-rectify_mono-4*.log
[camera/rectify_color-5] process has died [pid 23933, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=rgb/image_color image_rect:=rgb/image_rect_color __name:=rectify_color __log:=/home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-rectify_color-5.log].
log file: /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-rectify_color-5*.log
[camera/rectify_ir-6] process has died [pid 23955, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=ir/image_raw image_rect:=ir/image_rect_ir __name:=rectify_ir __log:=/home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-rectify_ir-6.log].
log file: /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-rectify_ir-6*.log
process[camera/depth_metric-9]: started with pid [24010]
process[camera/depth_points-10]: started with pid [24024]
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-11]: started with pid [24038]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12]: started with pid [24052]
process[camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-13]: started with pid [24066]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-14]: started with pid [24080]
process[camera/disparity_depth-15]: started with pid [24094]
process[camera/disparity_registered_sw-16]: started with pid [24108]
process[camera/disparity_registered_hw-17]: started with pid [24122]
process[camera_base_link-18]: started with pid [24136]
process[camera_base_link1-19]: started with pid [24147]
process[camera_base_link2-20]: started with pid [24158]
process[camera_base_link3-21]: started with pid [24169]
[FATAL] [1437514920.437059431]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1437514920.437109018]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1437514920.437109724]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1437514920.437385718]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1437514920.437533669]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1437514920.437575776]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1437514920.437748403]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1437514920.438395962]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1437514920.438403928]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1437514920.440145918]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1437514920.441588457]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1437514920.441830961]: Service call failed!
[camera/debayer-3] process has died [pid 23854, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/debayer camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=rgb/image_raw image_mono:=rgb/image_mono image_color:=rgb/image_color __name:=debayer __log:=/home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-debayer-3.log].
log file: /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-debayer-3*.log
[camera/depth_rectify_depth-7] process has died [pid 23971, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=depth/image_raw image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw __name:=depth_rectify_depth __log:=/home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-depth_rectify_depth-7.log].
log file: /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-depth_rectify_depth-7*.log
[camera/depth_metric_rect-8] process has died [pid 23993, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/convert_metric camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=depth/image_rect_raw image:=depth/image_rect __name:=depth_metric_rect __log:=/home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-depth_metric_rect-8.log].
log file: /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-depth_metric_rect-8*.log
[camera/depth_metric-9] process has died [pid 24010, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/convert_metric camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=depth/image_raw image:=depth/image __name:=depth_metric __log:=/home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-depth_metric-9.log].
log file: /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-depth_metric-9*.log
[camera/depth_points-10] process has died [pid 24024, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw points:=depth/points __name:=depth_points __log:=/home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-depth_points-10.log].
log file: /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-depth_points-10*.log
[camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-13] process has died [pid 24066, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=depth_registered/image_raw image_rect:=depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw __name:=depth_registered_rectify_depth __log:=/home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-depth_registered_rectify_depth-13.log].
log file: /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-depth_registered_rectify_depth-13*.log
[camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-14] process has died [pid 24080, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond rgb/image_rect_color:=rgb/image_rect_color rgb/camera_info:=rgb/camera_info depth_registered/image_rect:=depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw depth_registered/points:=depth_registered/points __name:=points_xyzrgb_hw_registered __log:=/home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-14.log].
log file: /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-14*.log
[camera/disparity_registered_sw-16] process has died [pid 24108, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/disparity camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond left/image_rect:=depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw right:=projector left/disparity:=depth_registered/disparity __name:=disparity_registered_sw __log:=/home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-disparity_registered_sw-16.log].
log file: /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-disparity_registered_sw-16*.log
[camera/disparity_registered_hw-17] process has died [pid 24122, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/disparity camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond left/image_rect:=depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw right:=projector left/disparity:=depth_registered/disparity __name:=disparity_registered_hw __log:=/home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-disparity_registered_hw-17.log].
log file: /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-disparity_registered_hw-17*.log
[camera/register_depth_rgb-11] process has died [pid 24038, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/register camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond rgb/camera_info:=rgb/camera_info depth/camera_info:=depth/camera_info depth/image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw depth_registered/image_rect:=depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw __name:=register_depth_rgb __log:=/home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-register_depth_rgb-11.log].
log file: /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-register_depth_rgb-11*.log
[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12] process has died [pid 24052, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond rgb/image_rect_color:=rgb/image_rect_color rgb/camera_info:=rgb/camera_info depth_registered/image_rect:=depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw depth_registered/points:=depth_registered/points __name:=points_xyzrgb_sw_registered __log:=/home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12.log].
log file: /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12*.log
[camera/disparity_depth-15] process has died [pid 24094, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/disparity camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond left/image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw right:=projector left/disparity:=depth/disparity __name:=disparity_depth __log:=/home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe8-11e5-9df0-6c626ddd8ab2/camera-disparity_depth-15.log].
log file: /home/crl/.ros/log/5a717a24-2fe
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214257/can-not-connect-kinect-using-openni/) by [BishopBishop](https://answers.ros.org/users/22070/bishopbishop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

install http://wiki.ros.org/freenect_launch
and use:
[roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch]
instead of openni.

---

Originally posted by [mehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/21123/mehdi/) with karma: 16 on 2015-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0